# porting c function to NASM

Tags: c, x86, nasm

I want to port this c++ function to NASM.

```
DWORD WINAPI Generic(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    __asm {
        mov eax, [lpParameter]
        call eax
        push 0
        call ExitThread
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have some problems understanding how lpParameter works here, and i have and error there when i compile this on NASM.

this is my current code:

```
BITS 32
global _start

_start:
mov eax, [lpParameter]
call eax
push 0
call exitfunk

exitfunk:
mov ebx, 0x0A2A1DE0
push 0x9DBD95A6
call ebp
cmp al, byte 6
jl short goodbye
cmp bl, 0xE0
jne short goodbye
mov ebx, 0x6F721347
goodbye:
push byte 0
push ebx
call ebp
```

any one can help me?

Comment: So, first it would help to understand WHAT error you get...

Comment: I imagine the error is that lpParameter is undefined. The compiler in the example above is helping a lot by resolving those variables and allowing references to be mixed in C and ASM. I would also imagine the lpParameter is the address of a C function, so the __asm code puts the address in EAX and then calls it via EAX.

Comment: sorry for that, it is like mark says, lpParameter is undefined and the function do that.

Comment: What are all those magic constants?

Comment: just part of the exit function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, NASM does not support named function parameters, and so you have to extract the parameters manually from registers or the stack. AFAIR, all Win32 API functions expect parameters on the stack, so you should replace this

```
mov eax, [lpParameter]
```

with this

```
mov eax, [esp+4]
```